# Перевод часов в формат

Tags: python, время

Я получаю время и оно у меня в таком формате

```
9 
12
```

И мне нужно конвертировать данную строку в

```
09:00
12:00
```

Пытался сделать это таким способом

```
from datetime import datetime 
lol = datetime.strptime('9', '%H:%M')
```

В итоге имею ошибку

Comment: Приложите свои наработки

Comment: from datetime import datetime

lol = datetime.strptime('9', '%H:%M')

Comment: но при таком раскладе у меня ошибка

Comment: что за ошибка то?

Answer (score 4):

Можно сделать гораздо проще, не импортируя при этом datetime

```py
time = 9
print(f"{time:02}:00") # > 09:00
```

Answer (score 3):

Ну, у вас же в строке только часы, без двоеточия и минут. Значит для разбора этой строки через `strptime` форматная строка должна быть просто `'%H'`:

```
from datetime import datetime

lol = datetime.strptime('9', '%H')
print(lol)  # 1900-01-01 09:00:00
print(f"{lol:%H:%M})  # 09:00
```

Ну и если всегда просто часы в виде числа приходят, можно без `strptime` обойтись, просто приведя строку к целому числу, потом передать полученное значение в `time` через параметр `hour` (если вам нужно только время, то логично использовать `datetime.time` вместо `datetime.datetime`):

```
from datetime import time

hours = '9'
t = time(hour=int(hours))
print(t)  # 09:00:00
print(f"{t:%H:%M}")  # 09:00
```